# Please help me simplify this complicated probability equation

Tags: probability

The equation is:

$A_n = \text{probability that the n-th unit in a circuit works} = (1-p)$.

$$P(\text{system works}) = P[(A_1 \wedge A_2) \vee A_3 \vee (A_4 \wedge A_5)]$$

I've verified that this is correct but don't know how to simplify it. In particular, I don't know how to apply the distributive and addition properties for two OR operations. Does anyone have concrete steps to show how to simplify this equation? Much appreciated.

Comment: A crucial missing hypothesis is that $(A_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant5}$ is independent. Then the answer is $$1-p^3(1-p)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using inclusion/exclusion: In general, $$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know where I can read a proof of this?

Comment: You've been given the keyphrase, "inclusion exclusion". Search for it, and ye shall find.

Comment: A fairly convincing argument (although perhaps not a strictly rigorous proof) can be found by looking at a Venn diagram of three sets in general position.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to turn OR into AND by asking when the system fails.
Use Prob(System works) = 1-Prob(System fails)
Prob(System fails) = Prob($A_1A_2$ fails and $A_3$ fails and $A_4A_5$ fails)
Then multiply the three probabilities together.